# How to parse nested arrays with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, multidimensional-array

I used to successfully parse the following .json file:

```json
[
    {
        "latitude": 49.419459253939316,
        "longitude": 8.676411621072491
    },
    {
        "latitude": 49.41946061080915,
        "longitude": 8.676411644939083
    },
    {
        "latitude": 49.420365910782735,
        "longitude": 8.676438042403413
    }
]
```

The following [Jackson script](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) outputs a `List` of points.

```java
private static <T> List<T> parseFile(final String fileName, 
                                     Class<T> contentType) {
    // ...
    InputStream inputStream = // Open file
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
        CollectionType collectionType = typeFactory
            .constructCollectionType(List.class, contentType);
        return objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, collectionType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now the dataset gets more complicated. The `List` of points becomes a `List` of `List` of points.
I structured it this way - please correct me if this is not correct.

```json
[
    [
        {
            "latitude": 49.419459253939316,
            "longitude": 8.676411621072491
        },
        {
            "latitude": 49.41946061080915,
            "longitude": 8.676411644939083
        },
        {
            "latitude": 49.420365910782735,
            "longitude": 8.676438042403413
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "latitude": 49.40460334213399,
            "longitude": 8.670034018853409
        },
        {
            "latitude": 49.404608057285145,
            "longitude": 8.670028775634165
        },
        {
            "latitude": 49.40506145685422,
            "longitude": 8.66955817506422
        }
    ]
]
```

I prepared the following POJOs to store the data into:

```
public class GeoPoint {
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
}
```

...

```
public class ThreePoints {
    public List<GeoPoint> points;  
}
```

How do I have to change the above Jackson parser so it can handle the nested arrays? Can Jackson parse the data into a nested class structure such as the `ThreePoints.class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple custom deserializer

To deserialize it to your class:

```
public class GeoPoint {
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
}

public class ThreePoints {
    public List<GeoPoint> points;
}
```

Write a custom deserializer:

```
class ThreePointsDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<ThreePoints> {

    protected ThreePointsDeserializer() {
        super(ThreePoints.class);
    }


    @Override
    public ThreePoints deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ThreePoints result = new ThreePoints();
        GeoPoint[] points = parser.getCodec().readValue(parser, GeoPoint[].class);
        result.points = Arrays.asList(points);
        return result;
    }
}
```

to use that deserializer:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(ThreePoints.class, new ThreePointsDeserializer());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);

TypeFactory tf = mapper.getTypeFactory();
CollectionType collectionType = tf.constructCollectionType(List.class, ThreePoints.class);

List<ThreePoints> result = mapper.readValue(YOUR_DATA, collectionType);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create additional collection type. See below code:

```
TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
CollectionType listType = typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, contentType);
CollectionType listListType = typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, listType);
List<List<GeoPoint>> readValue = mapper.readValue(json, rootCollectionType);
// convert to ThreePoints
```

**EDIT**
Unfortunately you are not able to tell `Jackson` to convert your `JSON` to your `POJO` classes because they do not fit to each other. `Jackson` also does not contain annotations which you can use to map your `JSON` to your `POJO` classes. You have to do it manually. Using my code you can write custom deserializer for `ThreePoints` class in which you can use inner `ObjectMapper` and my above code. I think, that you will be able easily convert `List<List<GeoPoint>> readValue` to `ThreePoints` class. Another option - you can write just a simple function in you `JsonUtil` class. If you really can not change this `JSON` you have to do it manually.

Comment: Can you please update your solution to show how I can produce a `List<ThreePoints>`?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the most elegant solution would be to use TypeReference

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<List<List<GeoPoint>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<List<GeoPoint>>>() {};
List<List<GeoPoint>> locations = mapper.readValue(jsonAsString, typeRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to read the values as Matrix,
first you need to map the values using a Pojo called Place.

```
public class Place {

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Second step, you  need to map the JsonNode into a Matrix.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.CollectionType;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory;


public class Main {
   static String jsonString =  "[" +
"    [" +
"        {" +
"            \"latitude\": 49.419459253939316," +
"            \"longitude\": 8.676411621072491" +
"        }," +
"        {" +
"            \"latitude\": 49.41946061080915," +
"            \"longitude\": 8.676411644939083" +
"        }," +
"        {" +
"            \"latitude\": 49.420365910782735," +
"            \"longitude\": 8.676438042403413" +
"        }" +
"    ]," +
"    [" +
"        {" +
"            \"latitude\": 49.40460334213399," +
"            \"longitude\": 8.670034018853409" +
"        }," +
"        {" +
"            \"latitude\": 49.404608057285145," +
"            \"longitude\": 8.670028775634165" +
"        }," +
"        {" +
"            \"latitude\": 49.40506145685422," +
"            \"longitude\": 8.66955817506422" +
"        }" +
"    ]" +
"]";

    public static void main(String...args) {
        final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
           final Place[][] dtos = om.readValue(new ObjectMapper()
               .readValue(jsonString, JsonNode.class), Place[][].class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: I would like to have it parsed into a `List`.