# Java: How to write a generic that deserializes a list/collection?

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, jackson

I'm attempting to refactor my deserialization method to use generics to enable me to deserialize any type. I can do this just fine for objects that are not in a collection, like this:

```
public static <T> T parseProductData(String jsonData, Class<T> typeClass) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    T inputMessage = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, typeClass);
    return inputMessage;
}
```

Here is the method that I want to refactor:

```
public static List<ComponentPOCO> parseJsonComponentFromString(String fileContents){

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                    .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
                    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            List<ComponentPOCO> component = mapper.readValue(fileContents, new TypeReference<List<ComponentPOCO>>() {});
            return component;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is my failed attempt to refactor the method to use generics:

```
public static List<T> T parseJsonComponentFromString(String fileContents, Class<T> typeClass){

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                    .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
                    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            List<T> component = mapper.readValue(fileContents, new TypeReference<List<T>>() {});
            return component;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However, this code doesn't compile because it's not using Java generics correctly. How could I deserialize my JSON objects into a generic list/collection/something-similar type?

Here is an example of the data that I'm deserializing into the `ComponentPOCO` class:

```
[
      {   "artifactPathOrUrl": "http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sample/sample.jar.zip",
        "namespace": "exampleNamespace1",
        "name": "exampleName1",
        "tenant": "exampleTenant1"
      },

      {   
        "artifactPathOrUrl": "http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sample-calculator/sample-calculator-bundle-2.0.jar.zip",
        "namespace": "exampleNamespace1",
        "name": "exampleName2",
        "tenant": "exampleTenant1"
      },
      {   
        "artifactPathOrUrl": "http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/helloworld/helloworld.jar.zip",
        "namespace": "exampleNamespace1",
        "name": "exampleName3",
        "tenant": "exampleTenant1"
      },
      {   
        "artifactPathOrUrl": "http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/fabric-activemq/fabric-activemq-demo-7.0.2.fuse-097.jar.zip",
        "namespace": "exampleNamespace1",
        "name": "exampleName4",
        "tenant": "exampleTenant1"
      }
]
```

Here is the code of the ComponentPOCO type:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import org.apache.pulsar.common.io.SinkConfig;
import org.apache.pulsar.common.io.SourceConfig;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Data
public class ComponentPOCO {
    @JsonProperty
    private String namespace;
    @JsonProperty
    private String tenant;
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty
    private String destinationTopicName;
    @JsonProperty
    private String artifactPathOrUrl;
    @JsonProperty
    private String className;
    @JsonProperty
    private List<String> inputs;
    @JsonProperty
    private String output;
    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, Object> userConfig;
    @JsonProperty
    private String logTopic;
    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, Object> configs;
    @JsonProperty
    private Integer parallelism;
    @JsonProperty
    public String sinkType;
    @JsonProperty
    private String sourceType;
    @JsonProperty
    public String runtimeFlags;
}
```

Comment: It is my personal but well considered opinion that including a rant against Java in a Java question is a bad idea. Same with calling Java generics implementation "not as intelligent" in a question that shows that you don't know much about the topic.

Comment: @fdreger The problem is actually well documented. See, for example, here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22642/what-is-wrong-with-javas-generics

Comment: You should build type in dynamic way: `mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, typeClass)`. See: [Using Jackson to deserialize into a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105723/using-jackson-to-deserialize-into-a-map/20109694#20109694) and [How to parse nested arrays with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273835/how-to-parse-nested-arrays-with-jackson/24274463#24274463)

Comment: Also, take a look on example [How do I parametrize response parsing in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581859/how-do-i-parametrize-response-parsing-in-java/57582505#57582505) and [Deserializing or serializing any type of object using Jackson ObjectMapper and handling exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299558/deserializing-or-serializing-any-type-of-object-using-jackson-objectmapper-and-h)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. The quickiest way to make this code work as I think you want is to replace the method with this one:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String,T> parseJsonComponentFromString(String fileContents){
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                    .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
                    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            return mapper.readValue(fileContents, new TypeReference<T>() {});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

because [`ObjectMapper.readValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue-java.lang.String-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference-) returns a `LinkedHashMap<String,T>` (I have no idea why it says just T in the javadocs)

Then you look up your parsed string with [`get(key_name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) if you know the keys or [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) if you don't and don't want to assume them. This last one is better but would require you to use java 8+ and to know about lambda expressions and functional interfaces. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-java-8/) a tutorial. [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-foreach-examples/) another one.

By the way, I take chance again to point out there is much wrong with this code, you may want to re-design your whole system. If you really really really must use a List, than you have a different problem: "*How to convert a LinkedHashMap to a List?*". Guess the quickiest way whould be implement the forEach mentioned earlier and push each element on the List.

That is, something like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> linkedHashMap = XXX.parseJsonComponentFromString(yyy);
LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();     
linkedHashMap.forEach((k,i) -> list.add(i));
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: What do you mean by "you may want to re-design your whole system"? My goal was to simply deserialize a collection/list/whatever of JSON objects so I could process each one. I'm not sure that I understand the design flaw there.

Comment: For example there is no point to use a List: just use the LinkedHasMap as I showed.
I just assumed stuff like that happened elsewhere in your project

Comment: What does the string in the LinkedHashMap represent?

Comment: It's the "name of the variable" on the [JSON](https://www.json.org/).
For instance, take the json:

`{
"a":100,
"b":"bruno",
"c":true
}`

The String represents the words "a", "b", or "c".

Comment: That violates my use case. My variables are not named. Please see the data in my edit.

Comment: It's because that is an array of Objects inside the json. It's something really different from the original question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199024/discussion-between-devinbost-and-sterconium).